# Вывод div блока по времени

Tags: javascript, html

Ситуация такая. Есть кнопка `popup`, при её нажатии появляется блок. Вопрос такой - можно ли выводить разные блоки в разное время? Допустим, с 13 00 до 15 00 выводится один блок, а когда 15 00 17 00 выводится другой. У меня была мысля сделать его через if. Но пока ничего не получилось. Буду рад парочке идей.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно и какраз через if лучше всего

```
var date = new Date();
var h = getHours();

var popuoURL = 'http://....';//URL для popup по умолчанию
var popupPar = { ... };//Параметры для popup по умолчанию

if(h>=13&&h<15){
    /*Параметры и URL для popup для с 13 до 15*/
}else if(h>=15&&h<17){
   /*Параметры и URL для popup для с 15 до 17*/
}//else ....

 window.open(popuoURL, 'my_popup', popupPar);
```

Другой вариант - в самом popup со времнем химичить. Тут уже зависит от того, что ты хочешь с ним делать: отображать/скрывать блоки, менять стили, текст и т.д. - также через date

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен объект [`Date`](http://javascript.ru/date) и, в частности, его метод [`getUTCHours`](http://javascript.ru/date/getutchours):

```js
    var date = new Date();
    alert(date.getUTCHours());
```